# Нужна ли запятае если говорится об одном объекте

Tags: пунктуация

> Но посторонних людей связывает что-то временное или не связывает ничего[,] и они могут прекратить отношения между собой

Нужна ли здесь запятая? В обоих подпредложениях говорится об одном объекте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужна ли здесь запятая?

**НУЖНА.** Разделяет части сложносочинённого предложения.